# Can't have multiple fiware/orion-ld docker images on the same server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fiware, fiware-orion

I am successfully running a `fiware/orion-ld` docker image on my server using this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
 orion:
  image: fiware/orion-ld
  hostname: orion
  container_name: fiware-orion
  depends_on:
   - mongo-db
  expose:
   - "1026"
  ports:
   - "1026:1026"
  command: -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel DEBUG
  healthcheck:
   test: curl --fail -s http://orion:1026/version || exit 1

 mongo-db:
  image: mongo:3.6
  hostname: mongo-db
  container_name: db-mongo
  expose:
    - "27017"
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: --nojournal
  volumes:
    - mongo-db:/data

volumes:
  mongo-db: ~
```

On another directory I have created a second `docker-compose.yml` file in order to start a second `fiware/orion-ld` server in order to check if I can have multiple docker orion-ld images on the same server. This is my secondary `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
 orion:
  image: fiware/orion-ld
  hostname: orion-test
  container_name: fiware-orion-test
  depends_on:
   - mongo-db
  expose:
   - "1021"
  ports:
   - "1021:1021"
  command: -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel DEBUG
  healthcheck:
   test: curl --fail -s http://orion-test:1021/version || exit 1

 mongo-db:
  image: mongo:3.6
  hostname: mongo-db
  container_name: db-mongo-test
  expose:
    - "27011"
  ports:
    - "27011:27011"
  command: --nojournal
  volumes:
    - mongo-db:/data

volumes:
  mongo-db: ~
```

Although it starts, in the end I get this:

```
fiware-orion-test | time=Wednesday 11 Mar 14:34:09 2020.119Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=orionld.cpp[1108]:main | msg=Startup completed
fiware-orion-test | time=Wednesday 11 Mar 14:34:09 2020.119Z | lvl=WARN | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=orionld.cpp[1114]:main | msg=Initialization ready - accepting requests on port 1026
```

It seems that I can't have a second copy of `fiware/orion-ld` image running on another port (other than 1026). Is that so? Am I doing something wrong?

(using centOS 7)

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem starting more than one instance or Orion-LD (or Orion for that matter) in the same machine. For help, use the `-u` CLI. Take special care about the database you want the second instance to use. The same or some other database.

Comment: Thanks. Where should I use the -u directive?

Comment: Simply run the broker with it:  

% orionld -u

You get an output looking something like this: 
kz@xps:context.Orion-LD> orionld -u
Usage: orionld  [option '-U' (extended usage)]
                [option '-u' (usage)]
                [option '--version' (show version)]
                [option '-logDir' <log file directory>]
                [option '-t' <trace level>]
                [option '-logLevel' <initial log level (NONE, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG)>]
                [option '-logAppend' (append to log-file)]
               
ETC (too long)

Comment: Just to clarify, the second instance or Orion needs to run on a different port (-port), a different pid-file (-pidpath) and possible a different database name (-db), and a different log-file directory. Using the CLI option -U   (uppercase u), you can see the default values, which is what the first instance of orion uses. For example, the default value of -logDir is /tmp - just look at the output of orionld -U